# jQuery function keeps looping without stopping

Tags: jquery, html, regex, ajax

I don't know what is wrong with this code. The code takes first line, checks it, then removes it and then checks the next line. However when all lines are empty the code keeps working; it will not stop.

```js
function getSocksListInput() {
  var socksList = $("#socks").val().split("\n");
  var getTheSocksLine = $.trim(socksList[0].replace(/\s+/g, ''));
  var getIP = $.trim(getTheSocksLine.split(":")[0]);
  var getPort = $.trim(getTheSocksLine.split(":")[1]);

  if (typeof getIP == "undefined" || typeof getPort == "undefined" || getIP == "" || getPort == "" && socksList.length != 0) {
    getNewSocks();
    console.log("i will not stop");
    getSocksListInput();
  } else if (getTheSocksLine.match(/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,6}$/) == null) {
    socksDieResultDisplay(getIP + ":" + getPort);
    getNewSocks();
    getSocksListInput();
  } else if (getIP == "" || getPort == "" || getTheSocksLine == "") {
    getNewSocks();
    getSocksListInput();
  } else {
    checkSocksLiveDie(getIP, getPort);
  }
}
```

If I change `socksList.length` condition to `!= 1` it will stop fine, however it won't check the last result. Why?

Comment: Why you **recursively** do `getSocksListInput();`? Clearly your checks are not well put. Therefore you enter a recursion and never exit. What does `getNewSocks();` do?

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You keep calling `getSocksListInput()` in almost all of your conditional branches - of course it keeps printing.

Comment: yes i need to keep calling it, because it keeps checking the lines, if i remove it, it checks only the first line and then stops.

Comment: then you need to pass some argument to it so that it knows to stop - or update the value it's parsing so it isn't stuck in the same conditional branch loop

Comment: what do i need to pass? i already said i passed the count of array and it is not working

Comment: i don't see anywhere where arguments are passed to that function. can you share some example input you're expecting? and what you're expecting to happen? as i read the code, it sounds like it's acting exactly as expected is what i'm saying. maybe i'm missing some additional context

Comment: oh wait. i think maybe i got it. change your first conditional to: `if((typeof getIP == "undefined" || typeof getPort == "undefined" || getIP == "" || getPort == "") && socksList.length != 0)`

Comment: thank you man for your help, however it doesn't work. anyway i'm changing the code right now i'll update if i can fix it